# Why the sentry exception does not send to servers in local environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sentry

I am using Rails and integrate with Raven gems. I also export the environment of SENTRY_DSN

I found the getsentry does not work until I use

```
  Raven.capture do

  end
```

to wrap the code

I don't want to use Raven.capture since it is not natural at all and cannot capture all exceptions. What's the reason?

Comment: Did either of the supplied answers work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Configure the [Sentry Rails plugin](https://docs.getsentry.com/hosted/clients/ruby/integrations/rails/) to send all exceptions to Sentry.

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure a whitelist of environments per the example in the docs?

https://github.com/getsentry/raven-ruby#more-configuration